# Facebook Stream.publish set permission based on attached media

Tags: php, facebook

I am in the process of making an app that uploads photos to Facebook and then optionally posts a link to the user's wall. I would like to know if it is possible to assign the same visibility permissions to the post as the photo or the photo album it is uploaded to. I am able to get the visibility permissions from the album fairly easily.

Is it possible to set the same permission to the wall post, and if so, how?

Clarification: I do not mean the client side permissions of the actual file. By permissions I mean the 'visibility' tag passed from the getAlbum(s) API. (i.e: Visibility: Everyone, Friends, Custom, etc)

That way, if the user sets an album to be only visible to his/her friends and they have elected to have a photo uploaded to that album that when the photo gets linked in their stream (wall) it has the same visibility settings as the album its located in.

Example: Joe creates a photo album on Facebook called "Summer Fun" that is only visible by his "Friends". Joe uses my app to upload a photo tho the "Summer Fun" album. I check the "Visibility" field of the album and see it is set to "Friends". Joe also wants a link to this photo posted to his wall, in which my app can easily do using the stream publish API. Due to his privacy setting of the "Summer Fun" album being set to "Friends" I would like my app to respect that setting when posting to the wall. Making the wall post only visible to the same group of people he calls his "Friends".

In other words, is it possible to set the group of people who can see a wall post programatically as if you were to hit the little 'Share' drop down on facebook.com and set it to 'Friends' only?

1. Language: PHP5
2. Using: Facebook's REST API, cURL, however open to alternatives if need be to get the
   end result I need.

Comment: unsure, I'd like to know also.

Comment: you have probably already seen this, but it is now possible.  See my revised answer.

Comment: yes, I have seen it! I'm very excited. Now I just need to find out how to get a list of the user's network ids and I'll be golden

Answer (score 2):

Jayrox, <strike>it seems that it is currently not possible</strike> [it is possible](http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=362) to set the visibility of wall posts programatically.

Quoting the article:

> When you want to display content a
>   user has created, check the privacy
>   for the content by querying the
>   object_id in the [privacy FQL table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Privacy_%28FQL%29) or
>   by calling [privacy.get](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Privacy.get).

If you retrieve the privacy settings the user assigns to his album, you can then assign the same privacy settings to the wall post via [Stream.publish](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish)

In addition, the **user** can customize what shows up on his wall via Application Settings and can control who can see his wall through his Privacy Settings; <strike>**applications** have no ability to change the visibility of wall posts (even if it is to restrict the visibility to even fewer people than the user's privacy settings would normally allow.)</strike>

In other words, the user can control who can see his wall and what can write to his wall, but he cannot set the visibility of certain wall posts.  If it is posted to his wall, it is visible to those who can see his wall posts.

However, there is one interesting question -- if a user has a group of people who can see his wall but are not allowed to see his notes, will those people:

**A)** Be able to see wall posts about new notes but unable to view them

**B)** Not see wall posts about new notes automatically.

If the answer is **B** then you should be fine already, since the user's privacy settings will take effect automatically.

**See:**

http://www.allfacebook.com/2009/02/facebook-privacy/

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/04/28/first-look-publishing-data-to-the-facebook-stream-using-the-new-stream-apis/

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions/Stream_permissions

Comment: Sean, example A is exactly what I am trying to work around/figure out/test.

When my app posts a photo and the user has selected to allow it to be cross posted to the wall I dont want people who can see his wall but cant see the album to see the wall post also. I dont know what they will see, if anything. I guess I should make a second Facebook account and test it out.

Comment: Also, Thanks for the additional links. I'll check them out from home tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just upload photos to facebook use this :

First Download this Library [facebook_php5_photoslib](http://eyermonkey.com/files/facebook_php5_photoslib.zip)

Then use this code

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook_api/facebook_php5_photoslib.php';

$appapikey = '[YOUR KEY]';
$appsecret = '[YOUR SECRET]';
$facebook = new FacebookPhotos($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user = $facebook->require_login();

$appcallbackurl = 'http://eyermonkey.com/FlickrTools/';  

//catch the exception that gets thrown if the cookie has an invalid session_key in it
try {
  if (!$facebook->api_client->users_isAppAdded()) {
    $facebook->redirect($facebook->get_add_url());
  }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  //this will clear cookies for your app and redirect them to a login prompt
  $facebook->set_user(null, null);
  $facebook->redirect($appcallbackurl);
}

// Get a list of the users albums
$albums = $facebook->api_client->photos_getAlbums($user, null);

// Pick the first album for sake of the example
$aid = $albums[0]['aid'];

$filename = 'http://eyermonkey.com/FlickrTools/test_image.jpg';
$caption = 'IM IN UR C0D. UPLOADING UR FOTOS!!1!';

// Perform the upload and get the return data (including the URL of the new photo)
// You can do what ever you want do with that url 
$upload_result = $facebook->api_client->photos_upload($filename, $aid, $caption);

// See the data that you have access to now that the photo is uploaded
echo '<pre>';
print_r($upload_result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: I'm currently able to upload photos without issue. The issue I am trying to resolve is posting a link to the phone on the user's wall that includes the same privacy settings as the photo and its album.